# slds v/s css style sheet in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds

I'm just curious to understand which one of the two - slds and css style sheets is better when it comes to performance. which one of the two is more preferable to be used.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SLDS and Custom css is better combination.
Using some other CSS might cause CSS rendering trouble (in combination to SLDS) also size of css will increase and hence more time to paint.

SLDS has everything provide so more faster to just plug than create.